# C/C++, choose between using global or passing argurment

Tags: c++, c, global-variables

Suppose function `f1` calls `f2`, `f2` calls `f3` and at last calls `f5`, each of them pass an argument "arg" to the callee, like the following:

```
f1(arg, ...) -> f2(arg, ...) -> f3(arg, ...) -> f4(arg, ...) -> f5(arg, ...)
```

Another way, use a global "arg", no need to pass argument "arg", like:

```
int arg = 5;
f1(...) -> f2(...) -> f3(...) -> f4(...) -> f5(...)
```

Which one is better? Or is there any method more useful?

Comment: Search the web for "global variables are evil".

Comment: If functions 2-5 are only used when called by the previous function, and so none of them are used outside of `f1`, then just have the first function take the argument and create the other 4 as anonymous functions within `f1` that will be able to see the variable which is scoped to `f1()`.  However, if `f2` through `f5` are used outside the context of being called in this chain from `f1`, then it seems they have to take an argument, right...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding argument 'arg' may make your functions independent and re-enterable that may be good, e.g, in multi-threaded application.
Using one global variable for a lot of function may result in an error when something changes the global variable value between any of two functions in the queue and you will get unexpected and invalid result.

Comment: You're right. Just feel too many duplications doesn't look so good.

Answer (score 0):

On some architectures, including [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) ([full spec in pdf](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)), the first few arguments are passed in registers. So if you always use `arg` in the same place in the argument list, and you use it consistently in all functions, then the compiler will probably take advantage of that to just leave it in the appropriate register.

Almost all ABIs use a register for the return value for a function; in some ABIs (ARM, for example), this is the same register as is used for the first argument. But not on x86-64: `eax` is used for the return value, and `rdi` or `rcx` (depending on platform) for the first argument. Anyway, juggling registers is nowhere near expensive as manipulating the stack, and manipulating the stack is not so expensive either.

So, personally, I wouldn't worry about the overhead. And globals will get you into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I would draw attention to the case when several arguments are passed. The situation becomes even worse:

`f1(arg1, arg2, ...) -> f2(arg1, arg2, ...) -> f3(arg1, arg2, ...) -> f4(arg1, arg2, ...)`

In this case it would make sense to define a structure and pass its reference:

```
struct MyParams
{
    int arg1, arg2;
};

void f()
{
   MyParams prms = { ... };
   f1(prms, ...) -> f2(prms, ...) -> f3(prms, ...) -> f4(prms, ...)
}
```

I would recommennd you to avoid using any global variables. The gain (if any) does not worth down sides.